# Client to the Server communication with Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, client-server

I am looking for a little advice. I want to build a live video chat application. I am really unsure what is the best alternative isfor the users to send text data messages.

I have read tutorials on the SharedObject.send method and the NetConnection.call() For the client to speak to the Server. However, i am still no clearer in my mind what the difference is? Please forgive me for the simplicity of this question but i am a newbie could these two alternatives work in a chat application were users are constantly send messages back and forth?

Comment: This is action script related, isn't it?

Comment: What programming language; what API? There are many libraries for this purpose, but we can't help you if we don't know *anything* about what your current situation is.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta type **AS3 video chat** in Google and you will get everything you want

I found

1. [simple video chat using as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869007/simple-video-chat-using-as3)
2. http://www.ironcoding.com/2011/02/flash-as3-video-chat-using-adobe-lccs/

From red5.org

> Red5 Media Server 1.0 delivers a powerful video streaming and
>   multi-user solution to the ©Adobe ©Flash Player and other exciting
>   client technologies.

You will of course find a lot more options. I mean, this is how I would have started if I wanted to build a video chat app :-)